# Javascript strings and objects

Tags: javascript

In js can I call a function in an object from a string? Hm, I show you with an example:

```
var Object = {
    callMe : function() { }
}

Object.callMe();
```

This I can do, but what if I want to do this:

```
var string = 'callMe';
Object.string();
```

Can I somehow do this? Maybe I'm just thinking wrong here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), like this:

```
var string = 'callMe';
Object[string]();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ALvdt/).

In JavaScript `obj.thing` ([dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation)) is accessing the same thing as `obj["thing"]` ([bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)).

Answer (score 3):

```
var myObject = {
  myFunction: function() { return "Hooray!"; }
}

var methodName = "myFunction";

alert( myObject[methodName]() );
```